# parse_str array return only last value

Tags: php, ajax

I am using ajax to submit the form and ajax value post as:

```
newcoach=6&newcoach=11&newcoach=12&newcoach=13&newcoach=14
```

In PHP I am using **parse_str** to convert string to array,but it return only last value:

```
$newcoach = "newcoach=6&newcoach=11&newcoach=12&newcoach=13&newcoach=14";
$searcharray  = array();
parse_str($newcoach, $searcharray);
print_r($searcharray);
```

Result array having only last value:

```
Array
(
    [newcoach] => 14
)
```

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: Perhaps it helps to submit  **newcoach** = newcoach1=6&newcoach2=11&newcoach3=12&
                 newcoach4=13&newcoach5=14

Comment: here its dataTable input value,am serializing the value and submitting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you set your argument **newcoach** multiple times, parse_str will only return the last one. If you want parse_str to parse your variable as an array you need to supply it in this format with a '**[ ]**' suffix:

```
$newcoach = "newcoach[]=6&newcoach[]=11&newcoach[]=12&newcoach[]=13&newcoach[]=14";
```

**Example:**

```
<?php
  $newcoach = "newcoach[]=6&newcoach[]=11&newcoach[]h=12&newcoach[]=13&newcoach[]=14";
  $searcharray  = array();
  parse_str($newcoach, $searcharray);
  print_r($searcharray);
?>
```

**Outputs:**

```
Array ( [newcoach] => Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 11 [2] => 12 [3] => 13 [4] => 14 ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is assigning the last value as all parameter have same name.

You can use `[]` after variable name , it will create newcoach array with all values within it.

```
$test = "newcoach[]=6&newcoach[]=11&newcoach[]=12&newcoach[]=13&newcoach[]=14";

echo '<pre>';
parse_str($test,$result);
print_r($result);
```

O/p:

```
Array
(
    [newcoach] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 11
            [2] => 12
            [3] => 13
            [4] => 14
        )

)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this function

```
function proper_parse_str($str) {
  # result array
  $arr = array();

  # split on outer delimiter
  $pairs = explode('&', $str);

  # loop through each pair
  foreach ($pairs as $i) {
    # split into name and value
    list($name,$value) = explode('=', $i, 2);

    # if name already exists
    if( isset($arr[$name]) ) {
      # stick multiple values into an array
      if( is_array($arr[$name]) ) {
        $arr[$name][] = $value;
     }
  else {
    $arr[$name] = array($arr[$name], $value);
  }
}
# otherwise, simply stick it in a scalar
else {
  $arr[$name] = $value;
    }
  }

  # return result array
  return $arr;
}


$parsed_array = proper_parse_str($newcoach);
```

Comment: Instead of inventing some useless functions, fix the origin of a problem - __wrong__ query string format.

Comment: and what if the query string format is written in this way ? i have properly tested this function and it is working fine.

Comment: @u_mulder its pasted from comments of [documentation](http://sg2.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php#76792)

Comment: yes i have pasted it, when i started giving link some says link may be going to expire please give a code, so i posted it.